# Logstash filter does not works on any logline

Tags: logging, logstash

I using this logstash configuration for filter my logs:

```
  input {
      udp {
        port  => 9600
        codec => json
      }
      tcp {
        port  => 9600
        codec => json
      }
    }

    filter { 
      mutate { add_field => [ "pod_id", "${POD_ID}" ] }
      if [docker.image] =~ /consul/ {
        mutate { add_field => [ "image_type", "consul" ]  }
      }
      else if [docker.image] =~ /image86/ {
        mutate { add_field => [ "image_type", "image86" ]  }
      }
      else if [docker.image] =~ /traefik/ {
        mutate { add_field => [ "image_type", "traefik" ] }
      } else {
        drop {}
      }


    }

    output {
      file {
       path => [ "${LOGSTASH_OUTPUT_PATH}/${NODE_ID}/%{image_type}-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log" ]
      }
    }
```

An example line for the logs:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-08-16T10:31:24.912Z",
  "stream": "stderr",
  "port": 58768,
  "@version": "1",
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "message": "\"Update /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/logstash-l0t1l/status\" [638.662326ms] [107.202µs] END",
  "pod_id": "logstash-h04h7",
  "docker": {
    "image": "gcrio.azureedge.net/google_containers/traefik@sha256:97a2133434e2d3b12afcc19d47c53bf4c3539eb8dab1ece0bc58cc9509",
    "hostname": "k8s-master-sdfsd1DC9D-1",
    "name": "/traefik_kube-system_0b2942b3e833432463ca0b767977a99e_0",
    "id": "fbc8bbbdaf2c3845008fc800a6134e2740eb72f9f705b0720a450a9c2d435c76",
    "labels": null
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

The problem with this one is that every message will be dropped and nothing go to the endfile. I am very beginner in logstash so can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `docker.image` value in the logstash filter, you have to use `[docker][image]`

Edit: The reference in the [logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references):

> The syntax to access a field is `[fieldname]`. If you are referring to a **top-level field**, you can omit the `[]` and simply use `fieldname`. To refer to a **nested field**, you specify the full path to that field: `[top-level field][nested field]`.

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, I enjoy receiving internet points B)